# Cannot get to work libqtx

Tags: qt, libqxt

I'm done everything like in this tutorial: http://qt-project.org/wiki/LibQxt_in_QtCreator

I've downloaded latest libqxt, it was builded with no errors. I've also copy pasted header files.

Now I have my application running, and I want to include QxtGlobalShortcut - but the IDE says to me there is no such file... How to resolve this problem?

My *.pro file

```
QT       += core gui
```

CONFIG  += qxt
QXT     += core gui widgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = QShot
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your pro file. I see two possible problems:

1. You tried to include `<QxtGlobalShortcut>`, but you actually need to include `<QxtGui/QxtGlobalShortcut>`
2. You've installed it wrong. Are there `qxt.prf` and `qxtvars.prf` in `$QTDIR/mkspecs/features`?

Comment: 1. When I Type #include <qxt in qt creator - creator doesn't autocomplete header name. On linux I have simmilar problem - but there in the header file <qxt/QxtGui/QxtGlobalShortcut> I have an error - cannot find "qxtglobal.h"
2. These files are missing for the folder on Ubuntu and on Windows (in the ubuntu i've installed libqxt-dev from repository)

Comment: What about the second one? Have you found `qxt.prf` and `qxtvars.prf`? Does QXT_INSTALL_HEADERS in `qxtvars.prf` points to the place, where your qxt headers are located?

Comment: I don't have those files on Ubuntu, and on Windows. It's weird - because on ubuntu I installed libqxt from repository.

Comment: Well, that might be the problem. On Windows I've compiled qxt from sources and I have those files. In Linux Mint I've installed qxt from repository and I found `qxt.prf` in `/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/features/`. `.prf` files are used by Qt to determine paths to include, libs e.t.c.